# How can I use pandas dataframe where such that I get only the true rows and don't get anything if the condition is not true

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, where-clause

So, let's say I have a pandas dataframe `dfObject` , say:

```
     A     B         C
1   red   square    big
2   green circle    small
3   blue  triangle  big
```

I am now trying to make another dataframe `dfBigObject`
To do this, I want to choose only those rows from the dataframe which have big in the C column

So, `dfBigObject` should look like:

```
    A     B         C
1   red   square   big
2   blue  triangle big
```

I try to use `df.where` to do this but am unsuccessful.

This is what I am doing:

```
dfBigObject = dfObject.where(dfObject.C == 'big')
```

However, this is returned:

```
     A     B         C
1   red   square    big
2    
3   blue  triangle  big
```

What can I do?

Code to create dataframe:

```
dfObject = pd.DataFrame()
dfObject.set_value(1, 'A', 'red')
dfObject.set_value(1, 'B', 'square')
dfObject.set_value(1, 'C', 'big')
dfObject.set_value(2, 'A', 'green')
dfObject.set_value(2, 'B', 'circle')
dfObject.set_value(2, 'C', 'small')
dfObject.set_value(3, 'A', 'blue')
dfObject.set_value(3, 'B', 'triangle')
dfObject.set_value(3, 'C', 'big')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) or [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
dfBigObject = dfObject[dfObject['C'] == 'big']
print (dfBigObject)
      A         B    C
1   red    square  big
3  blue  triangle  big
```

Or:

```
dfBigObject = dfObject.query("C == 'big'")
print (dfBigObject)
      A         B    C
1   red    square  big
3  blue  triangle  big
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way if you aren't trying to preserve the original shape of the dataframe (boolean indexing):

```
dfBigObject = dfObject[dfObject ['C'] == 'big']
```